# How to conciliate TinyMCE FileUpload and CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, tinymce, cakephp-4.x, tinymce-5

I am using TinyMCE for my views add() and edit() of my PagesController.
Following TinyMCE documentation, I am calling TinyMCE in my js file as below :

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '.tinymce',
    menubar: false,
    plugins: 'lists link image',
    toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist | link image',
    branding: false,
    image_caption: true,
    image_class_list: [
        {title: 'img-responsive', value: 'img-responsive'},
    ],
    image_title: true,
    automatic_uploads: true,
    mobile: {
        menubar: false,
        toolbar: [ 'undo', 'bold', 'italic', 'styleselect' ]
    },

    images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
        var xhr, formData;
    
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = false;
        xhr.open('POST', '/app/webroot/postAcceptor.php');
    
        xhr.onload = function() {
            var json;
    
            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                return;
            }
    
            json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    
            if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
                failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
                return;
            }
    
            success(json.location);
        };
    
        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());        
        xhr.send(formData);
    }
});
```

As you can see I am calling manually the file PostAcceptor.php.
This is working but I am conscious that this is not the optimal way to proceed.
Do I have to include the image_upload_handler directly in my views add() and edit() and create a new controller fileupload() instead of the postAcceptor.php file ?
I don't really know how to proceed properly. Also do you know if I can use getClientFilename() and moveTo() instead of postAcceptor content ?

postAcceptor.php

```
/***************************************************
 * Only these origins are allowed to upload images *
 ***************************************************/
$accepted_origins = [
    "http://localhost",
    "http://192.168.1.1",
];

/*********************************************
 * Change this line to set the upload folder *
 *********************************************/
$imageFolder = "img/";

if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"])) {
    // same-origin requests won't set an origin. If the origin is set, it must be valid.
    if (in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"], $accepted_origins)) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"]);
    } else {
        header("HTTP/1.1 403 Origin Denied");
        return;
    }
}

// Don't attempt to process the upload on an OPTIONS request
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "OPTIONS") {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS");
    return;
}

reset($_FILES);
$temp = current($_FILES);
if (is_uploaded_file($temp["tmp_name"])) {
    /*
      If your script needs to receive cookies, set images_upload_credentials : true in
      the configuration and enable the following two headers.
    */
    // header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    // header('P3P: CP="There is no P3P policy."');

    // Sanitize input
    if (preg_match("/([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])|([\.]{2,})/", $temp["name"])) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid file name.");
        return;
    }

    // Verify extension
    if (
        !in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), [
            "gif",
            "jpg",
            "png",
        ])
    ) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid extension.");
        return;
    }

    // Accept upload if there was no origin, or if it is an accepted origin
    $filetowrite = $imageFolder . $temp["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($temp["tmp_name"], $filetowrite);

    // Determine the base URL
    $protocol =
        isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on"
            ? "https://"
            : "http://";
    $baseurl =
        $protocol .
        $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] .
        rtrim(dirname($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]), "/") .
        "/";

    // Respond to the successful upload with JSON.
    // Use a location key to specify the path to the saved image resource.
    // { location : '/your/uploaded/image/file'}
    echo json_encode(["location" => $baseurl . $filetowrite]);
} else {
    // Notify editor that the upload failed
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: There's nothing magical about anything in the postAcceptor. No reason why you can't move that functionality into your Cake application, using the code mostly as-is, or changing it as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks but where would you implement the postAcceptor logic ? I am quite lost, I don't really know what to begin with...

Comment: Are you familiar at all with CakePHP? If not, there's lots of resources out there which will help you get started. Once you understand the basics of the MVC structure, it should become more clear how to organize this. The bits about origins and options would be best in some middleware, the data validation would be handled by a model, moving the file to where it should live would be either the controller or the model (depending on which you think should be "fat"), and the response finally sent by the controller. There's plugins too that could do almost all of this for you.